# Laravel queue data not being passed from constructor to handler

Tags: php, laravel, queue, laravel-queue

I'm having an issue with Laravel 5.6 queued job. I pass 3 arguments to the constructor. At this point, I checked and all the arguments have data. But when I run the job, one of these is empty in the handler.

This is the function that dispatches the job:

```
public function send() {
    $event = Evento::find($id);
    $subscribers = ParticipantesEvento::join('users', 'participantes_eventos.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
           ->select('users.name', 'users.email')
           ->where('evento_id', '=', $evento->id)
           ->get();
    $certificate = Certificado::where('evento_id', '=', $evento->id)->first();

    dispatch(new SendCertificatesByEmail($subscribers, $event, $certificate));

    return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Fazendo os paranauê...');
}
```

This is the job:

```
namespace App\Jobs;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;

class SendCertificatesByEmail implements ShouldQueue {

    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    protected $subscribers, $events, $certificate;

    public function __construct($s, $e, $c) {
        $this->subscribers = $s;
        $this->events      = $e;
        $this->certificate = $c;

        print_r($this->subscribers);   // Have data
        print_r($this->events);        // Have data
        print_r($this->certificate);   // Have data
    }

    public function handle() {
        print_r($this->subscribers);    // IS EMPTY!!!
        print_r($this->events);         // Have data
        print_r($this->certificate);    // Have data
    }
}
```

Although that Laravel's documentation says to declare the variables as protected in the job, I've already tried with them as public too. Same problem. I'm already out of ideas. What I'm doing wrong??

Comment: Can you just try putting `$this->subscribers = clone $s;`, just to see what happens?

Comment: @GTCrais Tried. Not working... =/

Comment: If it helps...Both variables are information from database. The only difference between the problematic variable and the others is that its a collection, with many subscribers. The other two have just one register each (one event and one certificate).

Comment: Try `$this->subscribers = "whatever";` to confirm / eliminate the problem being in the `$s` parameter.

Comment: I've already did this test. Assigning any "whatever" value to `$this->subscribers` in the constructor, the value appears normaly in the handler.

Comment: @GTCrais I've included in the question the origin of data passed to the job.

Comment: Hmm...well, I assume it can't serialize subscribers for some reason. Check out `SerializesModels` trait, and try to manually serialize / unserialize subscribers to see what happens...that's the only thing I can think of. It should be able to serialize a Collection of Eloquent models though...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your collection of eloquent models is not structured correctly. Because of this, Laravel cannot properly serialize them for dispatch and unserialize when the job is run.

When you send an eloquent model (or collection of models) to a queue job, Laravel only serializes the ids of the models when the job is dispatched. When the job is then processed, it takes the ids and retrieves the data from the database.

In this case, your `$subscribers` is an eloquent collection of `ParticipantesEvento` models. Also, because of your query, the only data your models have are the name and email of the user. So, when Laravel attempts to serialize the keys of this collection, it won't find any.

Even if you do update your query to include the `participantes_eventos.id` field on the model, when the job is run, your `subscribers` property will be a fresh collection of ParticipantesEvento models without the user data you included from your original query.

Your code is showing that what you really want your `$subscribers` to be are the users that are attached to the event. Assuming you have your eloquent relationships setup, you can just do this:

```
$subscribers = $event->users;
```

If you don't have your relationships setup, add this to your `Evento` model. This sets up the [many-to-many relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) from events to users through the `participantes_eventos` table.

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'participantes_eventos');
}
```

---

You can do the same thing with the certificate, too. Add this method to your `Evento` model to setup the [one-to-one relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one) from the event to the certificate:

```
public function certificate()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Certificado::class);
}
```

And then use it like so:

```
$certificate = $event->certificate;
```

Comment: I don't have this structure. I have the `eventos` table, that have 'id', 'name', 'description', etc. I have the `users` table that have 'id', 'name' and 'email'. And I have a `participantes_evento` table that "unites" the subscribers of each "evento" of the system, having the fields 'id', 'evento_id' and 'user_id'. Use `$subscribers = $evento->users;` will not work in this structure (yes, I know that its not the most correctly structure, but its what I have to deal).

Comment: I've just made a workaround for the problem....but I'll try to make this way and return if this works.

Comment: BINGO! That works perfectly, man! Thank you very much for help! Just add the `return` in the `certificate()` function, otherwise it throws an exception. I'll mark the answer as right! Thanks again!

Comment: @AndréRaubach Ugh, sorry for the typo and thanks for the edit. But, yes, what you've described is a many-to-many relationship, where the `participantes_evento` table is a pivot table that connects many users to many events, and vice versa. The `belongsToMany` relationship is how you model that in eloquent. Glad you got it working!

Answer (score 0):

Well...it seems that when the job is executed, the SerializesModels repeat the query of the Model and, for some reason, it goes bad. I've did a workaround...
In the function that I dispatch the job, instead of passing the Model to the job, I've made and array with the result. And pass this array to the job. In this way, the job will not repeat the query, but just read the static array received:

```
$inscritos = ParticipantesEvento::join('users', 'participantes_eventos.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
    ->select('users.name', 'users.email')
    ->where('evento_id', '=', $evento->id)
    ->get();

$insc = array();
foreach ($inscritos as $inscrito) {
    $insc[] = $inscrito;
}
```

But...

**ATTENTION:**

This could bring problems in some scenarios. Like said in this article: https://gistlog.co/JacobBennett/e60d6a932db98985f160146b09455988 , the advantage of the SerializesModel redo the query is to take updated data from the database. For example: if a user change your email or name in his/her register **after** I send the static array to the job, when the job executes it will work with outdated user information.

However, it did the trick for now...while I think in a more elegant solution to this issue. Thanks to all that helped!